# Homebrew mysql support

Tags: mysql

when I use Homebrew to install Mysql (Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.13), I can't change my password,this is my SQL:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=password('elephant7') WHERE user='root';
```

then error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('elephant7') WHERE user='root'' at line 1

how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

> This function is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html for the correct way to set a password:

```
ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string';
```